# Fabric js - how to not run loadSVGFromURL when the passing image url is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

```
    var lbr = (lengthbrsvg) ? lengthbrsvg : def_svg;
```

let's say `def_svg` is a valid image URL.
`lengthbrsvg` is dynamically set which is either image URL or empty.
Now `lbr` is valid image URL even if the `lengthbrsvg` is empty.
`loadSVGFromURL` function only accepts valid svg url. otherwise throws error. So the default image is passed when the `lengthbrsvg` is empty. We use `loadSVGFromURL` function inside another same function repeatedly to add svg to a canvas one by one. Due to the use of `def_svg` the number of request increases which is unnecessary. So, is there a way to not run that function if the image URL is empty which in turn dont request for `def_svg` image. in other words is there another way than using ternary operator.

```
    fabric.loadSVGFromURL(lbr, function(obj_lengthbr) {
            var lpatpath;
                lpatpath = new fabric.PathGroup(obj_lengthbr, { left: 0, top: 0, width: 620, height: 641 });
                lpatpath.setPatternFill({ source: lengthbrpattern, repeat: 'repeat', offsetX: 'left', offsetY: 'top' });
                canva.add(lpatpath);

            fabric.loadSVGFromURL((lengthbrbottom) ? lengthbrbottom : def_svg , function(obj_lengthbrbot) {
                var BorPath;
                //========
                //========
                 fabric.loadSVGFromURL( , function(obj_lengthbrbot) {
                      //=====
                      //=====
                 });
            });
        });
```

From the above snippet, I don't want to run the `loadSVGFromURL` if the passing image URL is empty. how do I achieve that?

Comment: Why you are not using only `if`?

Comment: how could you use if here? it's nested function. `If` condition affects the inner functions that are inside the conditional function.

Comment: Perform the `if` check before you enter fabric.loadSVGFromURL; no need to get fancy.